# Magento configurable product for products with date attribute

Tags: magento

**Background:** 
I am building a web shop with Magento. I am looking for a solution to present hotel rooms (virtual; options) for which I have a qty per date.

I have the following (example) scenario for my Magento webshop:

```
A hotel room for 2 nights for 2 persons on 01-01-2014 with qty 5
A hotel room for 2 nights for 2 persons on 02-01-2014 with qty 5
A hotel room for 2 nights for 2 persons on 03-01-2014 with qty 5
A hotel room for 1 night  for 2 persons on 01-01-2014 with qty 3
A hotel room for 1 night  for 3 persons on 02-01-2014 with qty 3
A hotel room for 1 night  for 4 persons on 03-01-2014 with qty 6
```

**Approach:** 
A combination of a configurable product with simple products was the solution that came to mind. Each row of the list above would be a separate simple product with an *amount_of_persons* and *arrival_date* attribute.

**Problem:** 
After setting up an attribute set with the custom attributes *amount_of_persons* (dropdown {1,2,3,4}) and *arrival_date* attribute (date), I wanted to create a configurable product based on this attribute set. Soon I learned that you can only create configurable products with an attribute set of attributes that have dropdown attributes (only).

If I would set the *arrival_date* to type dropdown and set it with string date options "01-01-2014" etc. It would work for the example above, but not for any other dates. Still I want to have one product as representation for the simple product set and reuse the attribute set.

**Question:** 
Is there a solution to present the a set of simple products as described above in a (configurable?) product so that the attribute set can be used for any (dynamic) date used in the simple products?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this problem?

Comment: @nano, no, we moved away from Magento completely and build something from scratch in Symfony2.